# Width Full Image - Maintain Aspect Ratio and Keep in Center Horizontally and Vertically

Tags: html, css, image

This code below works, but I would like it to maintain the absolute center of the image, not stretch it based on the top left corner.  See images:

**html**

```
 <div class="full-img-container">
 <img src="/images/crowd.jpg" class="full-img">
 </div>
```

**css**

```
.full-img-container {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**When the browser is small:**

[image]

**When the browser is stretched - it stays in 300px but isn't vertically centered (there should be more people in the image)**

[image]

## UPDATE

This is what I was trying to do: http://demo.solemone.de/overflow-image-with-vertical-centering-for-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

I think I know what you want now.  Interesting problem.  So vertical centering, with the possibility of cropping off even amounts of the top and bottom of the image due to the priority of keeping the center of the image in the center of your window.

I found an example that might help you at another website :

http://demo.solemone.de/overflow-image-with-vertical-centering-for-responsive-web-design/

Try his example and let me know if it works for you or at least gets you closer to your ideal solution!  I will try to help further as needed after I hear back from you.

Comment: Yes! This is what I want.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you have to use javascript (jQuery) in his solution but I think that is the only way to solve this for an <img tag....

Comment: Agreed. But this solution worked. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Set `height: auto;` to the `<img>` tag.

I think I misunderstood the question. The answer is: make the image block: `display: block;`.

Comment: isn't it `auto` by default?

Comment: It is auto as long as the height and width are not specified by HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    var imgheight = $('.full-img').height();
    var containerheight = $('full-img-container').height();

    heightDifference = imgheight - containerheight;

    if(heightDifference > 0)
    {
        $('.full-img').css('margin-top', '-' + heightDifference/2 + 'px')
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no background image

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set

background-size: contain;